# Get the google import contacts

Tags: android

How to get programatically the Google import contacts in android phone.please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

to get Google account information, Google provided step how to get contacts, creates new, add photo. 
refer this [link](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html)

Comment: you have implemented this code.First signup and other Firstname,lastname,address.Please help

Comment: i havnt tried, but it is successfully working as one of my friend worked on it. and further you can see @Pankaj answer for local phone contact, and remember to add permission of READ_CONTACTS.

Comment: No I donot want local phone contacts.I want when we sign up the gmail or gooogle accounts those import contacts in google or gmail accounts.

Comment: you cant create/sign up programmatically see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699008/can-i-create-a-google-account-programmatically

Comment: check this http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html you will get contact list and then you can add it in your DB

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class which I tried when I was novice for Android.

```
public class ReadGoogleContact extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final String[] GROUP_PROJECTION = new String[] {Groups._ID, Groups.TITLE };
        Cursor groupCursor = getContentResolver().query(Groups.CONTENT_URI, GROUP_PROJECTION, null, null, Groups.TITLE);
        if(groupCursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while(groupCursor.moveToNext()) {
                String groupId = groupCursor.getString(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(Groups._ID));
                String groupName = groupCursor.getString(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(Groups.TITLE));
                Log.i("GoogleGroup", "Group Id : " + groupId + " Group Name : " + groupName);
                printContacts(groupName, groupId);
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("GoogleGroup", "No any group found");
        }

        if(groupCursor != null || !groupCursor.isClosed())
            groupCursor.close();
    }

    private void printContacts(String groupName, String groupId) {//getGroupWiseContacts(String id) {
        Cursor cursor = this.managedQuery(Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Contacts._ID },
                GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { groupId }, Phone.TIMES_CONTACTED + " DESC");
        Log.i("GoogleGroup", "___________      " + groupName + "       ________________________");
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Log.i("GoogleGroup", "Contact id : " + cursor.getString(1) + " Display Name : " + cursor.getString(0));
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("GoogleGroup", "No any contacts with this group");
        }

        if(cursor != null || !cursor.isClosed())
            cursor.close();
    }
}
```

And more information you can refer this [docs](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html)

Comment: He dont want Local phone contacts buddy.

Comment: @hotveryspicy Yes you are right. He didn't put this in his question. So should I remove my answer?

Comment: no, its Ok. because contacts are contacts either local or web. people will get both from here