# How to create a Google account programmatically?

Tags: c#, google-admin-sdk

Does anybody know how to create gmail account in c# (programmatically). I am refer this link https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users.

Comment: I generated apikey successfully but I am not able create http request.

Comment: as above. bit of advise though, start with httpwebrequest

Comment: ok, is there we need to add any reference in project.

Comment: I hope this isn't going to be used to create spam accounts. Is it?

Comment: no, but I am stuck with creating web request.

Comment: @AnuragJain Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10027534/2246344) what you were looking for?

Comment: Create google account programmatically but when I send httpwebrequest, it's not working.

Comment: these is my POST request :- string URl = service + "?&type=xml" + "&APIKey=" + APIKey + "&UserName=" + UserName + "&GivenName=" + GivenName + "&FamilyName=" + FamilyName + "&Password=" + Password;

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: I post the code Please check it. If u think this code is useful for u please mark as my answer.

Comment: Duplicate of [Can I create a Google account programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699008/can-i-create-a-google-account-programmatically) - You need the Google Apps Provisioning Api

Comment: @Basic Thanks for reply, I all ready post the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This the code for create gmail account programmatically in c#:-

**Step 1:** You should have admin account.  Use admin mailid and pwd for create gmail account.

**step 2:**  login in your admin account then go into security tab -> Api Reference -> Enable Api Access.

**Step 3:** add Google.Gdata.Apps.dll in your project.

**Step 4:** code:

```
using Google.GData.Apps;

AppsService appService = new AppsService("example.com","mailid","Password");

try
{
    var a = appService.CreateUser(UserName,GivenName,FamilyName,Password);
}
catch (AppsException ex)
{
    response = ex.Reason.ToString() + " " + ex.ErrorCode.ToString();
}
```