# Is it possible to access and update Exchange accounts?

Tags: android

In my project I need to access the Exchange accounts on the device, to change them.

I need to do it programatically , inside my application.

I have searched around but it does not seem that there is a way of doing such a thing.

Please any help or suggestion?

---

EDIT EDIT

To be more specific i need to:
lists all email accounts on the device and allows the user to change settings for Exchange accounts:

*server address

*server port number

*SSL (on/off)

*accept all SSL certificates (on/off)

*account password

Comment: Lisa, Have you code anything  ?

Comment: @Kedarnath thanks Kedarnath, but I have no code since I have no idea on how to do it :-))) LISA

Comment: How about first [google](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=k1wpU5WvBerV8gedj4DwCw#q=Android%2Bcreate+email+account+programmatically) and then ask the question ? I think it is possible.

Comment: @Kedarnath I did it Kedarnath, believe me... no results

Comment: @Kedarnath I need to do it programatically , inside my application. I have found nothing abut it...

Comment: did you check the link, I gave you ? I have searched it for programmatically only.

Comment: @Kedarnath they do not address the issue, unfortunately...

Comment: While you are right. Have a look at to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/2699008/3330969

Comment: @Kedarnath thanks Kedarnath, even that is not what I am looking for...thanks anyway :-))))

Comment: If I am getting you correct then you want to do singup activity for suppose gmail account. i.e. creating a new gmail programmatically, Am I correct ?

Comment: @Kedarnath Hi Kedarnath, no I need to lists all email accounts on the device and allows the user to change settings for Exchange accounts:

*server address
*server port number
*SSL (on/off)
*accept all SSL certificates (on/off)
*account password

Comment: Ahh.. My mistake. I mis-interpreter your question title.

Comment: check [this](http://loganandandy.tumblr.com/post/613041897/caller-uid-is-different) article

Comment: @silwar thanks silvar, but I don see the point... :-(

Comment: In sort you can not. Until you have your own email client app.

Comment: @PankajKumar that was I suspect, I hope there is some kind of workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the permissions/settings of an another exchange account (it gives you a security error). You only can create your own exchange account witch it will be included in your exchange accounts as yourAppName..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at AccountManager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)

You should be able to do something like this:

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
Account[] accountList = accountManager.getAccounts();
for(Account account : accountList){
    accountManager.getUserData(account, AccountManager.KEY_USERDATA);
    accountManager.setUserData(account, AccountManager.KEY_USERDATA, "data");
}
```

Comment: @LisaAnne perhaps I misunderstood your question. Doesn't the code above list all the accounts on your device?

Comment: yes it does, thanks nyx, but what I need is a way to access the `*server address
*server port number
*SSL (on/off)
*accept all SSL certificates (on/off)
*account password` of the account, to be specific of an Microsoft Exchange Account

Answer (score -1):

Powershell is probably the tool that I would want to use to do this, but from devices it is tricky. Tools like AccountManager should assit with this as under the hood they are probably using Remote Powershell scripting. Alternatives that I can think of are:

1. Create your own web service that you can execute powershell commands from, and have your app connect to that. This is a good primer that works for Exchange 2010 and 2013: http://forums.asp.net/t/1683553.aspx?Mailbox+creation+in+Exchange+Server+2010+using+ASP+Net+3+5+application
2. Find a tool to execute remote powershell requests from the device direct. I have not tried this but this looks like a good thread to follow: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/bc1b417d-0388-486b-8742-305a48224a92/android-client-for-powershell-remote-scripting?forum=winserverpowershell

I personally already had web services hosted inside the domain that my app was using anyway (data source was in the domain), so I put my mailbox and AD user management service along side those, then the mobile apps made simple calls like CreateUser, EnableMailbox, CreateMailEnabledUser...

Comment: I'm not sure OP wants to modify the accounts on the server, just locally on the device.